# convert / change string to date format in google big query SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

the table in big query shows that variable "date" is a string.

How to convert string into date format? such as mmddyy, dd-mm-yyyy

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The `date` column from the `ga_sessions` tables is in the format `YYYYMMDD`, so to parse it as a date, you can use:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', date) AS date
FROM YourTable;
```

For example,

```
#standardSQL
WITH YourTable AS (
  SELECT '20170510' AS date UNION ALL
  SELECT '20170508'
)
SELECT PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', date) AS date
FROM YourTable;
```

If you want to change the date to a different format, you can use the `FORMAT_DATE` function, e.g.:

```
#standardSQL
WITH YourTable AS (
  SELECT '20170510' AS date UNION ALL
  SELECT '20170508'
)
SELECT
  date,
  FORMAT_DATE('%m%d%y', date) AS mmddyy_format,
  FORMAT_DATE('%d-%m-%Y', date) AS dd_mm_yyyy_format
FROM (
  SELECT PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', date) AS date
  FROM YourTable
);
```

You can read about the supported format elements for `PARSE_DATE` and `FORMAT_DATE` [in the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#supported-format-elements-for-date).